# Outputting PHP variable inside HTML

Tags: php, html, output

So the title may sound confusing, so here's a brief example.

Here's the php code (Wrapped in HTML);

```
echo '<br/><img src="<?php echo $filepath" alt="test" />';
```

And here's the output of that code in a source file;

```
<img src="&lt;?php echo $filepath;?&gt;" alt="test">
```

As you can see, the php code is shown rather than executed. Here's the full file of which the code is located in;

```
<?php include('_header.php'); ?>

<?php
$username = $_SESSION['user_name'];

$filesyst = array('png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'jpg'); 
foreach($filesyst as $val) { 
$path = 'avatar/'.$username.'.'.$val; 
if(file_exists($path)) { 
$filepath = 'avatar/'.$username.".".$val; 
} else { 
//default image to be loaded 
} 
}
?>

<?php

// HERE'S THE CODE ----------
echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "<br />";
echo '<br/><img src="<?php echo $filepath;?>" alt="test" />';


?>

<div>
    <a href="index.php?logout"><?php echo WORDING_LOGOUT; ?></a>
    <a href="edit.php"><?php echo WORDING_EDIT_USER_DATA; ?></a>
</div>

<?php include('_footer.php'); ?>
```

Any ideas on what's going on here? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're already in a PHP tag - don't open a new one. You need to concatenate the variable. `echo 'foo: ' . $foo . ', bar: ' . $bar`.

Comment: You're using opening and closing tags within php tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already in a php-block. Try this:

```
<?php

// HERE'S THE CODE ----------
echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "<br />";
echo '<br/><img src="'.$filepath.'" alt="test" />';

?>
```

Comment: Okay so upon using this code, I now get an error saying `Undefined variable: filepath` in this file. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You have to replace these lines in your original source. But maybe you did not assign your variable. Maybe your foreach is never looped, because you have no images in your directory of you have another error in your source

Answer (score 0):

You have some PHP code encapsulated in the string you're `echo`-ing. Try this instead:

```
echo '<br/><img src="' . $filepath . '" alt="test" />';
```